# Heatmap creation using ggplot for large genomic dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Dear StackOverflow community,

I have a very large data set with an extract that looks like the below:

```
                     AC010327.1   AC010368.1  AC010525.2
TGYR                     0          0          0.984
BHT                      0.1        0          0
THY_RHE                  0          0.0002     0
FJU_WJNKO                0          0          0
PAED_DISE                0.342      0          0
DID PID                  0          0.3821     0
```

Each column is a gene, this is 30,000 columns long. There are 9 rows in total each a code for a disease type. The figures represent a statistical test outcome that is between 0-1 that has been run for that disease against the gene type.

I would like to present this mass of data in an easy to view form and thought a heatmap would be most suitable.

Using:

```
x <- data
x <-as.data.frame(x)
heatmap(x, scale - 'none')
```

Gets me a pretty ugly block of data.

I have been trying ggplot2 with geom_tile but keep getting error messages. I am slightly unsure what the "aes" function of this would be as I haven't names my row or coloumn names.

I can provide more information if needed but would be grateful for some guidance?

Many thanks

Update 13/2/18

[Using solution below, is there a way of weighting it in preference to results greater than 0?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqeG7.png)

Comment: Sorry the data frame came out incorrectly. see below

Comment: can you post a link to your ugly heatmap and explain what you don't like about it? What do you want viewers to be able to see in your graph?

Comment: Dear Ben,https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mEF38DJW3OoSRe7hIny1KKOPv5U5jLkP, as you can see from the image there are thousands of coloumns, the issue being that the majority of results are 0 (all numbers are between 0 and 1). Ideally i'd weight it so the non 0 values came across better.....

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the data frame from wide format to long format, and then use the `geom_tile`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Disease") %>%
  gather(Gene, Value, -Disease)

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Gene, y = Disease, fill = Value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "                     'AC010327.1'   'AC010368.1'  'AC010525.2'
TGYR                     0          0          0.984
                  BHT                      0.1        0          0
                  THY_RHE                  0          0.0002     0
                  FJU_WJNKO                0          0          0
                  PAED_DISE                0.342      0          0
                  'DID PID'                  0          0.3821     0",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Dear www, many thanks for the help. I have posted my attempt above (it doesn't look anywhere near as good and I have subset the data to only 5000 (of 30000) genes. Is there a way of accentuating the non-zero results?

Comment: @tac Please see this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178597/how-to-create-a-continuous-scale-with-distinct-custom-color-and-value-breaks-wit You may want to cut your values into different classes by quantile, or other methods, and then use discrete color for each class.

Comment: @tac To me coloring is a new question while your original question is about how to use `geom_tile` from `ggplot2` to plot your data. If this part has been solved, please consider to accept my post as the answer. See this post to learn how to do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

When you are observing covariance (difference among different variables), and suppose the check/test is with two categorical variable like yours, its always better to use geom_tile for a fairly medium size dataset.

But when your dataset is huge that it cant be seen in geom_tile, then its better to use d3heatmap

I can show you an example with a large dataset, which you can also try and is similar to your dataset.

```
library(d3heatmap)
url <- "http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv"
nba_players <- read.csv(url, row.names = 1)
d3heatmap(nba_players, scale = "column")
```

The result can be opened in web browser and can be played interactively
An example result can be seen in this site: [Output](https://rpubs.com/jcheng/nba1)

[Check this site for more information](https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/06/24/d3heatmap/)

**Notes**

1. The dataset should be a numeric dataset, d3 heatmaps won't accept any negative values or any characters
2. To avoid the problem you can make a percentage share for each row or column